# Windows Store In-App purchases (addons, consumables, subscriptions)?

Tags: windows-8, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, windows-store-apps, windows-store

1. Is it possible to have the following items be purchased through the Windows Store as in-app purchases?

   - Add-On
   - Consumables (One-Time Usage)
   - Subscriptions
2. Where can I find resources on how to code in in-app purchases for Addons, Consumables, Subscriptions?

---

Yes, I have attempted to google examples, but I can't seem to have any luck finding anything on some of these other than tech articles about Windows 8 rather than dev blogs/articles.

Comment: Did you try googling for "Windows 8 in-app purchases"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[To support in-app purchases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067.aspx) do the following:

1. Setup your app for licensing using the [`LicenseInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.aspx) class (this class also is where you put time limits on the purchase for subscriptions).
2. Name as code the feature in your app:

```
if (licenseInformation.productLicenses.lookup("featureName").isActive) 
{
    // the customer can access this feature
}
else 
{
    // the customer can't access this feature
}
```

1. Configure the in-app offer in the Windows Store

> Before you submit your app to the store, add each in-app offer to the
>   Advanced features page in the Submit an app workflow. This is where
>   you specify the in-app offer's token, price, and feature lifetime.
>   Make sure that you configure it identically to the configuration you
>   set in WindowsStoreProxy.xml when testing, or all of that hard work
>   you spent testing may be wasted!

There is currently no support for consumables (unless maybe you're using the xbox live api?).  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsstore/thread/07222726-3adc-4d49-91d7-ed64381b8057) for more details and a workaround.

Comment: It sounds like this answer is saying yes to addons and subscriptions? But, I'm not sure if you're saying yes or no to consumables.

Comment: in app purchases are surely allowed and supported via the Windows Store hence the RequestProductPurchaseAsync api, consumables aren't (although paypal has an sdk out for WinRT integration)

Comment: Ah, yeah, somehow I said in-app purchases twice.